# Prerequisites for Introductory Algebraic Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I have had courses on Group Theory and Rings and Modules loosely based on Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra textbook. I also had a course in General Topology based on Kumaresan/Munkres' Topology textbooks.

Are these enough prerequisites to take a course on Introductory Algebraic Topology? We would just be doing topics of the first chapter of Allen Hatcher's book

Comment: Yeah, probably. Though I'd also recommend skimming through chapters 7-13 of Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" as this gives a gentle introduction to the topic as a whole, before diving into Hatcher. Also this is probably not necessary since I just realized you mentioned "first chapter" of Hatcher.

Comment: @user I think you are definitely well equipped to jump into Hatcher. Notably, there is some overlap with the end of Munkres' textbook and the beginning of Hatchers

Comment: Yes, first few chapters of Allen Hatcher overlap with last 6 or 5 chapters of Munkres' book on Topology.